# What VNC server is compatable with realvnc viewer?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, realvnc

I have RealVNC Client on my mobile phone , and am not able to get the RealVNC server running on my windows 7 (tried some fixes , no luck) . So am wondering if it is possible to download other vnc servers which are compatable with realvnc client ??

if not , i have RDP working fine on my phone now , but the problem is i need to connect as an administrator to the windows 7 (not any other user) and that i need this administrator WITHOUT A PASSWORD for login , but with password for RDP . and when i connect through RDP , i don't want that admin to be logged off , is that possible ???

means when the PC boots up , i want to be automatically logged in without need to enter a password , then get my phone to connect to RDP for that logged in user but WITH A PASSWORD . and when RDP connects , i don't want that user to be logged out .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to set the account to login automatically, but with a password enabled.

This link shows XP, but I'm 90%+ sure that the syntax is the same for 7:
http://wiki.ljackson.us/Control_Userpasswords2

These are two other ways to get the the control panel item:

WinKey+R > control userpasswords2

Start > Search > netplwiz

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/). I have it running on several Win 7 machines and the install was 'uneventful'.

Answer (score 1):

VNC is a protocol, all the servers and clients use the same protocol and can be mixed invisibly. They may each have additions, but it's never much. I personally use Screen Sharing and Mocha VNC to control Mac Screen Sharing and TightVNC on windows.

TightVNC doesn't require you to set a password, and you can tell it to only accept people from the same network (ie lan). From what I understand, RDP is just Microsoft's attempt at VNC, it may work, but you're better off with VNC.

Comment: In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is. I had quite some frustrations with VNC clients not liking certain servers (or the other way round).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried every combination and now for years have been very happy with TightVNC as the server (on a Windows 8.1 machine) and RealVNC Viewer (iPhone, Mac, and PC versions).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but just in case others stumble upon here like I have.

A few notes on RealVNC Server/Viewer, the free versions of the server don't work over the internet, they coded it this way on purpose, RealVNC allows windows authentication, but found to be less reliable then using VNC authentication, is also better to use actual IP address for connections and stay away from using windows host names, and always include port even if default is used.

Funny thing about Windows, it disables RDP for accounts without a password, and I have yet to get it to work without it logging off or locking out the current user, I have seen it done before without logging the user out, but that was only on a computer part of a domain group set to netlogon only.

I stumbled upon here looking for a Linux VNC server compatible with the RealVNC viewer, because I have been using RealVNC server for years, and want only ring to rule them all.